# MVC validation should return boolean or array

Tags: php, validation

I have an action to reset user password. I already create `reset_password_token`, `reset_password_token_created_at`.

The validation rules are: token exist and reset_password_token_created_at - today <= 1. Each rule has different message

**First question:** I think validation is a business logic so I put the rule in `UserModel` <~ right?

**Second question** If validation should put in model, then validation should return boolean, an array or set of number (-1, 0, 1). I used php in the example bellow (the code may not right)

If return boolean, then the controller receive result and return a message based on that result, but how can I detect its false on rule 1 or rule 2 to set message (each rule has different message)

Ex: UserModel.php

```
// first solution return boolean
private function reset_password_validator($token) {
   $user = User::find_by_token($token);

   if (!$user) return false;
   $created_date = $user.reset_password_token_created_at;
   if (mktime() - strtotime($created_date) > 1) return false;
   return true;
}
// call in controller
$result = User::reset_password_validator($token);
```

If return array, should I directly return error message or return a number.
Ex:

```
private function reset_password_validator($token) {
    $user = User::find_by_token($token);

    //return error message   
    if (!$user) return array('error' => true, 'message' => 'Not exist');
    $created_date = $user.reset_password_token_created_at;
    if (mktime() - strtotime($created_date) > 1) {
        return array('error' => true, 'message' => 'Too late');
    }
    return array('error' => false, 'message' => 'success');

    //return status_code
    if (!$user) return -1;
    $created_date = $user.reset_password_token_created_at;
    if (mktime() - strtotime($created_date) > 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

If return a set of number (-1, 0, 1)

```
private function reset_password_validator($token) {
     $user = User::find_by_token($token);

     //return status_code
     if (!$user) return -1;
     $created_date = $user.reset_password_token_created_at;
     if (mktime() - strtotime($created_date) > 1) {
         return 0;
     }
     return 1;
}
// call in controller
$result = User::reset_password_validator($token);
if ($result == -1) echo 'Not exist';die;
if ($result == 0) echo 'Too late';die;
echo 'Done';die;
```

What should I do ? If you have a better solution, please tell me. Thanks a lot
ps: sorry, my english is very bad

Comment: @Gacek use exception to throw a message in model and get the message in controller, right ?

Comment: Whenever you want. You can throw error in function and catch it where you call function. If no exception is cast, then you can assume it was success